# How to handle reminder email alerts without duplicate sends from multiple conditions met

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow, email-alert

How would I handle this scenario...

When a record is created it has an expiry date. I want to send separate email reminders to the record owner 45,35,25,15,5 days before the expiry date.

I have a workflow that just has the Rule Criteria TRUE - so it triggers for every record created.

I add 5 time-based actions to the rule, which send the reminder email. 45 Days before ForeCastEndDate, Another rule with 35 Days before ForeCastEndDate etc.

However, if somebody enters a record with an expiry date in say 3 days time, it will immediately trigger all 5 Email Alerts and they get the email 5 times.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CreatedDate in your Criteria:

i.e. CreatedDate LESS TAHN Last 30 Days for the 35 days before criteria

or something similar to meet your business needs

Comment: That would require creating a workflow rule for each alert. Right now I think the OP has one workflow rule with multiple time-based actions.

Comment: Well I wouldn't object to 5 workflows if it does what I need, I'm just trying to figure out how I could use CreatedDate to do this. It's not immediately obvious to me how I would code it.